# What's the DC for Hatchling's Flame?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

> **Saving Throw: Reflex half**
>
> You focus a burning aura of energy at the end of your blade. It forms
> a seething sphere that, after a moment, bursts into a torrent of
> energy.
>
> The Desert Wind discipline teaches its students how to unleash their
> ki as burning energy. This maneuver allows you to create a wave of
> fire that sweeps over your enemies. When you initiate this maneuver,
> you blast forth a cone of flame that deals 2d6 points of fire damage.
> This maneuver is a supernatural ability.

Out of the 3 "X's Flame" maneuvers of Desert Wind, Hatchling's Flame is the only one that does not specify a DC even if it says "Saving Throw: Reflex Half", so, what's the DC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Spell save DCs are usually (10 + spell level + spellcasting ability modifier), so we should expect something similar to be true for maneuver DCs.

Oddly, the actual rules don't seem to make this explicit -- they just say that the DC will be specified in the maneuver text.

Some related swordsage disciplines have a DC of (10 + level + WIS modifier):

- the Dragon's Flame maneuver, which is a Swordsage 5, has a DC of (15 + WIS modifier).
- the Blistering Flourish maneuver, which is a Swordsage 1, has a DC of (11 + WIS modifier).

Hatchling's Flame is a Swordsage 2, so it should have a DC of (12 + WIS modifier).

Answer (score 5):

### The DC should be 12 + your Wisdom modifier

This indeed unspecified by the text of the manoeuvre, but in almost all cases the save DC for a manoeuvre is based on the "10 + level + ability modifier" formula, just the same as when calculating spell save DCs.

*Hatchling's Flame* is a swordsage 2 manoeuvre so it would have a base DC of 12, and manoeuvres in the Desert Wind family use Wisdom as the relevant ability score, so you'd add your wisdom modifier to get your final DC.

*Inferno Blast*, on the next page, also doesn't specify an actual save DC - but following the same formula, as a 9th level manoeuvre it would have a DC 19 + Wis mod save.